# how to call another activity from an image button

Tags: android, android-intent

how to call another activity by image button

I want when the user taps on an image button it will go to video.xml

how can I do it?

Comment: What code you have written inside `goToUrl()`?

Comment: here is the code

    private void goToUrl (String url) {
     Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
      Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl); startActivity(launchBrowser);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, declare your videoButton variable

```
private Button videoButton;
```

Then, in your MainActivity, instantiate your button variable and set up your onclick listener

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        videoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.single_ticket_add);
        videoButton.setOnClickListener(videoButtonOnClickListener);
    ...
```

Then have your goToVideoOnClickListener start an intent to open your VideoActivity

```
private OnClickListener goToVideoOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {           
                Intent intent = new
                Intent(MainActivity.this, VideoActivity.class); 
                startActivity(intent);      }
        };
```

Then in VideoActivity in OnCreate set your content view to be the layout video.xml

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video);
        ...
```

Comment: where do I declare videoButton variable? on the main.java or the video.java?

Comment: After public class MainActivity extends Activity{ and before private void onCreate ... I recommend http://www.vogella.com/ if you are looking for tutorials on android basics

Answer (score 0):

just create another activity for that video. and call it using intent like below:

```
Intent i = new Intent(firstact.this,videoact.class);
startActivity(i);
```

set your video.xml into video activity as:

```
setcontentview(R.layout.video);
```